# single-property GQL causes unexpected composite index

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

If I execute this GQL query:

```
GQLQuery("SELECT user FROM MyUser WHERE foo = :1", fooz)
```

It will cause my index.yaml to make a composite index with both the `user` and `foo` properties.

```
- kind: MyUser
  properties:
  - name: user
  - name: foo
```

And if i delete that index, when it's uploaded to App Engine and my app runs, an error appears
`no matching index found`.

I just don't understand why GAE must create a composite index for that query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is [fully documented here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Indexes_for_Projections):

> Projection queries require all properties specified in the projection to be included in a datastore index.